How to Add Material Symbols/Icons to a Devexpress DxButton icon
Adding a material symbol or icon to a devextreme DxButton is not documented on official devexpress site.
The following code will try to add a material symbol as icon DxButton, but it icon will not show up:
<dx-button 
 icon="material-symbols-outlined emoji_emotions">
 </dx-button>

Only devextreme icons and other external libraries like font awesome will work adding the icon name and related classes, but not material-icons nor material-symbols.

I found a solution to make the the icon to show, and consists on add a class on your global styles for each icon you want to include on DxButtons with the following structure:
.<iconName>:before {
content: '<iconName>';
}

For example:
.emoji_emotions:before {
content: 'emoji_emotions';

}
After adding a class for each material symbol I planned to use I'm now able to include material symbols on DxButtons.
